# Can we import data from BigQuery into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm only seeing how to load data to my bigquery database but i don't see any wiki or post to help me on my question : Is it possible to load data to an external source like google sheet from a bigquery database (that can go thought the cloud storage plateforme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can export data from BigQuery, yes. One way to bring BigQuery data into Google Sheets is with the new Google Sheets Data Connector, see the screenshot below for where you'll find this on the GS interface:

[image]

Once connected, you can then write an SQL query and pull this data directly into a Google Sheet.

Here's a link to some official documentation on this data connector: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9077536

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept my answer is you found it helpful!